# Is there a page that contains all the shortcuts for chat?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there a page that contains all the shortcuts for chat?

For instance, in chat you can use tag with:

```
[tag:tag-name]
```

or the

```
>
```

character or the use of backticks.

There must be a lot more cool tricks you can do in chat, but there seems to be no documentation about that?

Comment: The [chat faq](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting) may be a start :)

Comment: Now I feel a bit stupid :(

Comment: We can still post undocumented features as answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

One feature I don't see on the FAQ page is the ability to have links displayed as images even if they don't have a file extension typical of an image — just prepend an exclamation mark.  Like so:

```
!http://example.com/image.php?id=1
```